# Custome delimiter file upload using pyspark function not working

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-storage, apache-spark-sql

I am using below function to upload custom delimiter file.

```js
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import *
 

def loadFile(path, rowDelimeter, columnDelimeter, firstHeaderColName):
 

    loadedFile = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(path, "org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat",
                                      "org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable", "org.apache.hadoop.io.Text",
                                      conf={"textinputformat.record.delimiter": rowDelimeter})
 
 
    rddData = loadedFile.map(lambda l:l[1].split(columnDelimeter)).filter(lambda f: f[0] != firstHeaderColName)
        
    return rddData
```

I called the function below.

```js
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import *

Schema = StructType([
        StructField("FlightID", StringType(), True),
 StructField("Flightname", StringType(), True),
 StructField("FlightNo", StringType(), True),
 StructField("Depaturetime", StringType(), True),
 StructField("ArrivalTime", StringType(), True),
 StructField("FromPlace", StringType(), True),
 StructField("ToPlace", StringType(), True),
 StructField("Cremember", StringType(), True)
 
 
        
        

])

Data= loadFile("wasb://Accountnumber@serviceaccount.blob.core.windows.net/Flightdetails.txt",
                     "\r\n","#|#","FlightID")
                     
FlightDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Data,Schema )
FlightDF.write.saveAsTable("Flightdetail")
```

Source file size is 2GB, the process keeps on running. table is not creating in Azure.

What wrong am I  doing?

Comment: It seems that there was not obvious issue in your code, besides the file path. Please use `wasbs://` instead of `wasb://` and try again. Any update, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: I changed wasb:// to wasbs:// , but still the same issue. The code is keep on running.but not table is creates in Blob storage.

Comment: Per my experience, I think you need to check the directory named `Flightdetail` whether exists on the hdfs.

Answer (score 0):

Would recommend trying with a smaller dataset or couple of rows. 2 GB data-file may have some data anomalies which may be causing this issue.